# How to compress or resize image before uploaded in ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, angular7, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app , and image uploaded. but the uploaded image size is bigger . now i want to resize image before uploading. below my image uploading codes given.

```
selectImage(e: any) {
this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0];

var file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
var pattern = /image-*/;
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
  this.url = event.target.result;
  this.popoverController.dismiss(this.url);
  console.log('url for image:', this.url);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFile);

if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
  alert('invalid format');
  return;
}
}
```

Comment: I think doing this on server side will be much better than doing this in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had nothing to do with ionic itself, you can use a node package like ngx-pica, the instruction is very straight forward [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pica)

Comment: it is same as ionic resizer.

Comment: @gausmohammadshaikh, yes you can use that one too